# C# WPF MVVM TabItem HeaderTemplate won't work?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am currently working on an application with a *TabControl*, and every tab has a ViewModel which inherits from `ITabViewModel`, which has two properties: `HeaderText` and `HeaderImage`. I would like these to be set from each ViewModel. Thus, I attempted to use a `HeaderTemplate` style, but this did not work. Could anyone tell me how I could get this to work?

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding HeaderImage}" Height="20" Margin="5, 0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderText}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>

    <TabItem DataContext="{Binding ViewModelStart}">

    </TabItem>

    <TabItem DataContext="{Binding ViewModelStartupManager}">

    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define the DataTemplate under the ItemTemplate section

```
 <TabControl>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
```

And so on with your bindings

> ItemTemplate is the template used to format each item in the ItemsSource to create the headers

Answer (score 0):

I think there are at least two options for you.

**first**(I assume that `ViewModelStart` and `ViewModelStartupManager` are properties):

```
 <TabItem Header="{Binding ViewModelStart}">
 <TabItem Header="{Binding ViewModelStartupManager}">
```

**second**, use `ItemsSource` and define your tabs in some collection in ViewModel.

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel> Tabs{ get; set; }
```

XAML, remove your`TabItem's` and add them to property above. Also add following attribute to `TabControl`:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
```

Comment: I wanted to do the second option originally, however how would I add content besides just the header? I have lots of complex elements in each tab. I also have a DockPanel that acts as a secondary header in each tab, and has the same properties as the header (image and text), plus some others to look good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Header` property of a`TabItem` for the `HeaderTemplate` to get applied:

```
<TabItem DataContext="{Binding ViewModelStart}" Header="{Binding}">

</TabItem>

<TabItem DataContext="{Binding ViewModelStartupManager}" Header="{Binding}">

</TabItem>
```

This works:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding HeaderImage}" Height="20" Margin="5, 0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderText}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>

    <TabItem DataContext="{Binding ViewModelStart}" Header="{Binding}">

    </TabItem>

    <TabItem DataContext="{Binding ViewModelStartupManager}" Header="{Binding}">

    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```